# GCSE; Find the possible value of m

Tags: circles

[image]

Hello everyone! I hope someone could help me with this exercise! I tried to find the solution but I didn’t find the right response.

My atempt was the following:

I have substituted $y=mx + 2$
Group the terms like so:

$(1+m^2) x^2 + (4-2m)x + 2 = 0$

This is now of the form $ax^2 + bx + c = 0$ where $a = 1+m^2$, $b = 4-2m$, $c = 2$

But I don’t know what to do next...

I set the discriminant of the quadratic (in terms of m) to zero, and I solve it! And the right solution was m = -2 + root 6 Thank you all!

Comment: Can you show your attempt? It would help a lot in terms of helping you correct your approach

Comment: Two curves being tangent to each other means that they intersect at exactly one point.  Intersection is the graphical interpretation of solving algebraically. So, figure out the condition for which the two curves have exactly one solution.  And please use [mathjax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) to format your post.

Comment: Hint: Try using the discriminant approach.

Comment: Thank you for your responses!!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Equation of tangents from external point to a circle](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2507739/equation-of-tangents-from-external-point-to-a-circle) Once you have the general case, you can apply it to any problem of this form, even if it does use matrices. Found using [Approach0](https://approach0.xyz).

Comment: $m$ is one single constant. The question is, what should the values of $x$ be.  Just solve for $x$ and interpret $\pm$ sign.