# what is the characteristic equation f(x) in this article?

Tags: linear-algebra, analytic-geometry, determinant, matlab, quadratic-forms

in the article:

http://i.cs.hku.hk/~ykchoi/quadrics/Ellipsoid_Separation.pdf

in example 1

if I set a=3; b=2; c=4; xc=-9; yc=0; zc=0; r=5; and

f(x)=-(x/a^2+1)*(x/b^2+1)*(x/c^2+1)*(x+r^2)+x*(x/c^2+1)*(x/b^2+1)*(xc/a)^2+ x*(x/a^2+1)*(x/c^2+1)*(yc/b)^2+x*(x/a^2+1)*(x/b^2+1)*(zc/c)^2=0;

the calculated roots are different from what mention in the article, why?

for the calculation I use this on matlab:

syms a b c r xc yc zc x

a=3; b=2; c=4; xc=9; yc=0; zc=0; r=5;

[cc]=solve(-(x/a^2+1)*(x/b^2+1)*(x/c^2+1)*(x+r^2)+x*(x/c^2+1)*(x/b^2+1)*(xc/a)^2+x*(x/a^2+1)*(x/c^2+1)*(yc/b)^2+x*(x/a^2+1)*(x/b^2+1)*(zc/c)^2==0,x)

Comment: I've retagged your question with geometric tags, but I wasn't sure which ones were the most appropriate. Feel free to retag again. Also, could you clarify what you mean by $E^3$, and maybe tell us in what context you encountered these notions?

Comment: A title of a book would be best. Or link to an article

Comment: You might find [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/316849/intersection-of-conics-using-matrix-representation) and [this article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conic_section#Intersecting_two_conics) helpful.

Comment: http://i.cs.hku.hk/~ykchoi/quadrics/Ellipsoid_Separation.pdf

Comment: this is the article I am trying to understand. I understand why the ellipsoid is X^TAX=0, but I don't understand how they got

Comment: f(λ)=det(λA+B); in page 2 in http://i.cs.hku.hk/~ykchoi/quadrics/Ellipsoid_Separation.pdf